# database backup in jelastic can't be done from the app node

Tags: postgresql, jelastic

My **Goal** is to have an automatic database backup that will be sent to my s3 backet

Jelastic has a good [documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/postgresql-backup-restore) how to run the pg_dump inside the database node/container, but in order to obtain the backup file you have to do it manually using an [FTP add-ons](https://docs.jelastic.com/postgresql-backup-restore#docs-internal-guid-858ec0cb-411e-b72f-c591-26f08e8806ab)!

But As I said earlier my goal is to send the backup file automatically to my s3 backet, what I tried to do is to run the pg_dump from my app node instead of postgresql node (hopefully I can have some control from the app side), the command I run basically looks like this:

```
PGPASSWORD="my_database_password" pg_dump --host "nodeXXXX-XXXXX.jelastic.XXXXX.net" 
-U my_db_username -p "5432" -f sql_backup.sql "database_name" 2> $LOG_FILE
```

The output of my log file is :

```
pg_dump: server version: 10.3; pg_dump version: 9.4.10
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

The issue here is that the database node has a different pg_dump version than the nginx/app node, so the backup can't be performed! I looked around but can't find an easy way to solve this. Am open to any alternative way that helps to achieve my initial goal.

Comment: We can help you in this matter, provide us the full name of your environment with details at support@jelastic.com

Comment: The solution is to update the pg_dump version in the nginx/app container or you can add a docker node with the required pg_dump version to the environment. Keeping all available pg_dump versions in all types of compute nodes is not a good solution.